# How to remove a string from a list of strings if its length is lower than the length of the string with max length in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, list, string-length

*How to remove a string from a list of strings if its length is lower than the length of the string with max length in Python 2.7?*

Basically, if I have a list such as:

```
test = ['cat', 'dog', 'house', 'a', 'range', 'abc']
max_only(test)
```

The output should be:

```
['house', 'range']
```

'cat''s length is 3, 'dog' is 3, 'house' is 5, 'a' is 1, 'range' is 5, 'abc' is 3. The string with the highest length are 'house' and 'range', so they're returned.

I tried with something like this but, of course, it doesn't work :)

```
def max_only(lst):
    ans_lst = []
    for i in lst:
        ans_lst.append(len(i))   
        for k in range(len(lst)):
            if len(i) < max(ans_lst):
                lst.remove(lst[ans_lst.index(max(ans_lst))])
    return lst
```

Could you help me?

Thank you.

**EDIT: What about the same thing for the min length element?**

Comment: For the min length, just replace `ax` with `in` and `>` with `<` in any of the answers given

Comment: @gnibbler: and my starter value for `minlength` should be `float('inf')` instead of `-1` for `maxlength`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, true. You could instead make `minlen = 0` and `itemlen = -len(item)` ...

Comment: @gnibbler: Also a posibility; I'd stick to `1` in that case still to allow for empty strings.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, The way your code is written, you'll append the empty strings correctly regardless

Comment: @gnibbler: Sure, but I rather be explicit.

Answer (score 7):

Use a list comprehension and `max`:

```
>>> test = ['cat', 'dog', 'house', 'a', 'range', 'abc']
>>> max_ = max(len(x) for x in test)    #Find the length of longest string.
>>> [x for x in test if len(x) == max_] #Filter out all strings that are not equal to max_
['house', 'range']
```

Comment: @Totems way of finding `max_` seems quite a lot faster than the genexp

Comment: @gnibbler: Simeon used `len(max(lst, key=len))` first.

Answer (score 4):

A solution that loops just once:

```
def max_only(lst):
    result, maxlen = [], -1
    for item in lst:
        itemlen = len(item)
        if itemlen == maxlen:
            result.append(item)
        elif itemlen > maxlen:
            result[:], maxlen = [item], itemlen
    return result
```

`max(iterable)` has to loop through the whole list once, and a list comprehension picking out items of matching length has to loop through the list *again*. The above version loops through the input list just once.

If your input list is not a sequence but an iterator, this algorithm will still work while anything that has to use `max()` won't; it'd have exhausted the iterator just to find the maximum length.

Timing comparison on 100 random words between length 1 and 9, repeated 1 million times:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import random
>>> import string
>>> words = [''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(1, random.randrange(11))]) for _ in range(100)]
>>> def max_only(lst):
...     result, maxlen = [], -1
...     for item in lst:
...         itemlen = len(item)
...         if itemlen == maxlen:
...             result.append(item)
...         elif itemlen > maxlen:
...             result[:], maxlen = [item], itemlen
...     return result
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('f(words)', 'from __main__ import max_only as f, words')
23.173006057739258
>>> def max_listcomp(lst):
...     max_ = max(len(x) for x in lst)
...     return [x for x in lst if len(x) == max_]
>>> timeit.timeit('f(words)', 'from __main__ import max_listcomp as f, words')
36.34060215950012
```

Replacing `result.append()` with a cached `r_append = result.append` outside the `for` loop shaves off another 2 seconds:

```
>>> def max_only(lst):
...     result, maxlen = [], -1
...     r_append = result.append
...     for item in lst:
...         itemlen = len(item)
...         if itemlen == maxlen:
...             r_append(item)
...         elif itemlen > maxlen:
...             result[:], maxlen = [item], itemlen
...     return result
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('f(words)', 'from __main__ import max_only as f, words')
21.21125817298889
```

And by popular request, a `min_only()` version:

```
def min_only(lst):
    result, minlen = [], float('inf')
    r_append = result.append
    for item in lst:
        itemlen = len(item)
        if itemlen == minlen:
            r_append(item)
        elif itemlen < minlen:
            result[:], minlen = [item], itemlen
    return result
```

More fun still, a completely different tack: sorting on length:

```
from itertools import groupby

def max_only(lst):
    return list(next(groupby(sorted(lst, key=len, reverse=True), key=len))[1])[::-1] 

def min_only(lst):
    return list(next(groupby(sorted(lst, key=len), key=len))[1])
```

These work by sorting by length, then picking out the first group of words with equal length. For `max_only()` we need to sort in reverse, then re-reverse the result. Sorting has a O(NlogN) cost, making this less efficient than the O(2N) solutions in other answers here or my O(N) solution above:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('f(words)', 'from __main__ import max_only_sorted as f, words')
52.725801944732666
```

Still, the sorting approach gives you a fun one-liner.

Comment: Very elegant! And particularly, this would work with a generator that you can't run through again.

Comment: This just goes to show, sometimes the long way is the best way.  Nice work!

Comment: But do you have to use `l` as a variable name?

Comment: @gnibbler: there, removed that little wart for you. :-)

Comment: This is quite an interesting result. I wonder, what's the big-O complexity for the wasted calls to `append`?

Comment: @gnibbler: `.append()` is a constant cost (amortized). There is no additional *algorithmic complexity* here. There are also fewer than N such appends.

Comment: @gnibbler: but worst case is a list sorted on word length, in that case you use `.append()` N times.

Comment: Yes, and the extra append calls in the worst case will change your timeit score. I think for a random list, there will actually be relatively few wasted append calls on average. We don't really need to worry about getting the worst case by chance, and if we know the list is sorted by length we can do better than O(N). Noone tried starting with `sort(test, key=len)` but because sort is so fast compared to regular Python code, n may have to become quite large before the log(n) component starts to lose

Comment: @gnibbler: Yes, for a sorted input list taking the last or first set of items would work just fine. (`list(next(itertools.groupby(sorted(lst, key=len), key=len))[1])` for the minimal set, `list(next(itertools.groupby(sorted(words, reverse=True, key=len), key=len))[1])[::-1]` for the maximum set).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `max()` which returns the largest item in the list.

```
>>> len_max = len(max(test, key=len))
>>> [x for x in test if len(x) == len_max]
['house', 'range']
```

If you then take all the strings that have the same length as the element you get the desired result.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, that's interesting. I have fixed it by passing a proper `key` function.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Friday afternoon complex solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> test = ['cat', 'dog', 'house', 'a', 'range', 'abc']
>>> filter(lambda x,m=max(map(len, test)):len(x)==m, test)
['house', 'range']
```

For Python3.x you would need to use `list(filter(...))`

Comment: @MartijnPieters, no - `m` is only computed once

Comment: Ick, so it is; it is a keyword argument, I missed that.

Comment: Still, O(N) with two loops, so higher constant cost than my one-loop version.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you'll need to run it a lot of times to make up for the extra time spent typing though :)

Comment: See my updated post; 1000 words varying in length between 1 and 10 characters, my solution is 60% faster than Ashwini's. Feel free to repeat the experiment on Python 3. :-P

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
max_len = len(max(test, key=len))

result = [word for word  in test if len(word) == max_len]
```

Comment: Ok, I believe I left something out

Comment: Now you are on par with Ashwini's solution. :-)